Output Latest Contribution
I must be missing something, but there must be a way of outputting the latest contribution for a contact in search results (particularly if there is a mailmerge token for it), but I can't seem to find it.

This technique will work for any related entity (activities, event registrations, etc).
The basic steps for obtaining the latest Contributions for a contact are:

In SearchKit, search for contacts
With Contributions
Group By Contact ID

For every Contribution-related field you add to the Select Fields, (contribution date, amount, etc) choose "First" as the aggregate function, and Order By Contribution date, descending.


This will pick the latest contribution for each row.

Ah, thank you. I should have worked that out. Saves a lot of faffing in unfeasibly large Excel files.
